# Sorting a column that contains "Not Available" string values in R

Tags: r

In R, I'm trying to find the minimum value for a column contains character data-types.  Most of the column's values are actually numbers, but some values are just the string "Not Available".

I was just using this to get the values.

```
minRate <- min(myRows[,columnIndex], na.rm = TRUE)
```

That appeared to work for most of my tests.  However, since the values are strings, values like "10.3" are getting sorted lower than values like "8.6", because "10.6" comes before "8.6" alphabetically.

So then I added "as.numeric" to the mix as follows:

```
minRate <- min(as.numeric(myRows[,columnIndex]), na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, now I get a warning saying, "NAs introduced by coercion".  Also, an "NA" is returned as the answer, as opposed to an actual (incorrect) numeric value.

Is there a way I can remove the "Not Available" values and still get the real minimum value from this column?

Comment: Use `na.strings = "Not Available"` in `read.csv/read.table` while reading the data and you don't have to convert to `numeric`.  Regarding the problem you mentioned, it could be that the column is `factor` class.  So converting to `numeric` coerces to integer type

Comment: @akrun - Please add this as an answer.  It helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we have strings that specify missing values as "Not Avaiable", it is easier to specify the concerned string/strings in `na.strings` argument in `read.table/read.csv`

```
df1 <- read.csv("file.csv", na.strings = "Not Available", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

If we don't specify the `na.strings`, then the numeric columns would be read as read as `factor/character` (depending on the option `stringsAsfactors`).  Then, we have to convert those columns to `numeric` (more work)

Answer (score 1):

`stringAsFactors = FALSE` this argument can help to prevent the automatic coercion when read data. In other way try to coerce as character first as numeric, to avoid factor level coercion problems in direct numeric coercion: `min(as.numeric(as.character(...)))`